# How can I change external program to open org URLs for one org file only

Tags: org-mode, org-link, buffer-local

In my Emacs config, I have set Firefox to be the browser to open URLs with,

```
  (setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-firefox)
```

Now, I have one org-mode file, in which I would like to open URLs with a different program (`mpv`, to be precise).

What I'm currently trying is a buffer-local variable, indicated by a mode line

```
# -*- browse-url-browser-function: 'browse-url-chromium -*-
```

at the top of my org file.  However, whenever I click on an org-mode link pointing to a URL (or, just click on a URL, for that matter), I get an error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp quote)
  browse-url("https://www.google.com/")
  (lambda (path) (browse-url (concat "https:" path)))("//www.google.com/")
  org-open-at-point()
  org-open-at-mouse((mouse-2 (#<window 1244 on testfile.org> 192 (163 . 95) 82295534 nil 192 (20 . 4) nil (3 . 9) (8 . 19))))
  funcall-interactively(org-open-at-mouse (mouse-2 (#<window 1244 on yoga.org> 192 (163 . 95) 82295534 nil 192 (20 . 4) nil (3 . 9) (8 . 19))))
  call-interactively(org-open-at-mouse nil nil)
  command-execute(org-open-at-mouse)
```

I would appreciate any pointer towards how I can resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is caused by this quote:

```
# -*- browse-url-browser-function: 'browse-url-chromium -*-
___________________________________|
```

It shouldn't be there.

### Open video path in MPV on *nix OS's

Add this line to the init file(*.emacs*), or evaluate in Scratch buffer

```el
(org-add-link-type "mpv" (lambda (path) (browse-url-xdg-open path)))
```

`browse-url-xdg-open` uses `xdg-open` program that exists on all *nix desktops("X Desktop Group"). It check file extension to decide which program on desktop should open that path.

### Custom link in org mode:

```
[[mpv:/somepath_to_a_file/some_filename.extension]]
```

**mpv:** prefix, or any other defined by `org-add-link-type`
Actually it would open any file according to MIME type known to *xdg-open*. It would be MPV video player for a video file if it's configured as a default player on a desktop.

Comment: You can have Emacs create this line for you if not sure of the syntax. Try: `M-x add-file-local-variable-prop-line`, which will prompt you for the variable and the value to set.

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I could not figure out how to directly assign a function to a file variable using mode lines.  What I ended up having to do was define a function that set the local variables that I wanted, and use a `Local Variables:` section at the end of the file to call the function.

```
  (defun set-mpv-local-variables ()
    "Set local variables for using mpv"
    (set (make-local-variable 'browse-url-browser-function) 'browse-url-chromium))
```

Then at the bottom of your org document add:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (set-mpv-local-variables)
# End:
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html

If you only want to set one variable, just inlining the `set` expression may be enough, but if you need to set more than one local variable, I'd split it out into a separate function as I did here.

Answer (score 0):

A [link abbreviation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Link-Abbreviations.html#Link-Abbreviations)

```
#+LINK: mpv elisp:(browse-url-xdg-open "%s")
```

in the .org file is a neat way to add a custom link type such as mpv: just for the current .org file.